# CentOS 6.6 Gateway config getting crushed

Tags: networking, centos6, gateway

I got here a strange issue ... my default gateway return "0.0.0.0" even when my config looks good, to me at least.

Situation :

```
CentOS 6.6
2 Network card : eth2 = 1 public, eth3 = 1 private 
Public IP : 51.XX.XX.XX/32
Public Gateway : 151.XX.XX.XX
```

So I've configured the

```
/etc/sysconfig/network

     GATEWAY=151.XX.XX.XX
     GATEWAYDEV=eth2

/etc/sysconfig/netword-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
     DEFROUTE=yes
     NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Result :

```
cmd : route

Dest : default, Gateway : *, Genmask : 0.0.0.0
```

-> no IP from the network file

and when i do :

```
 ip route replace default via 151.XX.XX.XX dev eth2
```

It works but ofc it's non persistent

I've tried so far :

```
Config with the GW with  /etc/sysconfig/network
Config with the GW with  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2 -> does not even set the 0.0.0.0 def GW
Config with the GW with  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth2 -> does not even set the 0.0.0.0 def GW
```

Cheers

Comment: No one? No idea ? :(

Comment: thanks myself, we can't add GW which is not in the same network ... so i need to Set and replace or find a way to redirect to the good GW any idea here ?

Comment: Thanks for your help all :) Resolution : set a route that lead to the GW without via route then set the gateway which is now known by the interface.